# Cocos2D X: How to check if a key exists for a plist file?

Tags: c++, ios, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

I am using the following code to read data from plist for my game:

```
int levelNum = SOME_VALUE_FROM_OUTSIDE;

ValueMap mapFile = FileUtils::getInstance()->getValueMapFromFile("LevelDetails.plist");

std::string strLevel = std::to_string(levelNum);

ValueMap mapLevel = mapFile.at(strLevel).asValueMap();
```

LevelDetails.plist is a plist with dictionary as root. The problem is there can be occasions where there is no key named levelNum / strLevel. So I have to check if the key exists before I run this line:

```
ValueMap mapLevel = mapFile.at(strLevel).asValueMap(); //Throws exception occasionally
```

So what is the proper way to check if a key named levelNum / strLevel exists or not?

Answer (score 0):

Because ValueMap is a std::unordered_map, you can use the methods from that class:

```
if (mapFile.count(strLevel).count() > 0) {
    ValueMap mapLevel = mapFile.at(strLevel).asValueMap();
}
```

Declaration of ValueMap in cocos2d-x is:

```
typedef std::unordered_map<std::string, Value> ValueMap;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the `find` method which will return an iterator to the key-element pair or a past-the-end iterator if the key isn't found.

```
auto it = mapFile.find(strLevel);

if (it != mapFile.end()) {
    it->first; //key
    it->second; //element
}
else {
    //key not found
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I came across this question for a similar reason and think I have found an appropriate solution, using *cocos2d-x-3.11.1* (should also be applicable for older versions).

```
if( mapFile.at(strLevel).getType() != Value::Type::NONE ){
//OR if( mapFile[strLevel].getType() != Value::Type::NONE ) {

    //if reached here then the 'key exists', thus perform desired line.
    ValueMap mapLevel = mapFile.at(strLevel).asValueMap();
}
```

You could also check against a specific type defined in "CCValue.h" such as:

```
Value::Type::MAP
```

Answer (score 0):

What we use is this:

```
    string fullPath = cocos2d::FileUtils::getInstance()->fullPathForFilename("file.plist");

    auto dataFromPlist = cocos2d::FileUtils::getInstance()->getValueMapFromFile(fullPath);

    if (!dataFromPlist["key1"].isNull())
    {
       auto map = dataFromPlist["key1"].asValueMap();
       //Do something else
    }
```